Error TargetInvocationException or NullReferenceException when deploying ASP.NET Core 8 Web API to AWS Lambda
I'm trying to deploy my ASP.NET Core 8 Web API in AWS Lambda/API gateway. As I'm using .NET 8, it comes with Program.cs as start up file over StartUp.cs.
When I try to "Test" my lambda function through AWS console, it throws this following error

"errorType": "TargetInvocationException",
"errorMessage": "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.",
"stackTrace": [
"at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions)",
"at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.Bootstrap.UserCodeLoader.Init(Action1 customerLoggingAction) in /src/Repo/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/UserCodeLoader.cs:line 125",   "at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.Bootstrap.UserCodeInitializer.InitializeAsync() in /src/Repo/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/UserCodeInitializer.cs:line 46",   "at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.LambdaBootstrap.InitializeAsync() in /src/Repo/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/LambdaBootstrap.cs:line 164"   ], "cause": {   "errorType": "InvalidOperationException",   "errorMessage": "A public method named 'ConfigureProduction' or 'Configure' could not be found in the 'Program' type.",   "stackTrace": [   "at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StartupLoader.FindMethod(Type startupType, String methodName, String environmentName, Type returnType, Boolean required)",   "at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StartupLoader.FindConfigureDelegate(Type startupType, String environmentName)",   "at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(Type startupType, HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services, Object instance)",   "at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.InitializeServiceProvider()",   "at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()",   "at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.AbstractAspNetCoreFunction2.Start()",
"at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.AbstractAspNetCoreFunction2..ctor(StartupMode startupMode)",   "at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.AbstractAspNetCoreFunction2..ctor()",
"at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction..ctor()",
"at DeviceTrackerNFC.LambdaEntryPoint..ctor()",
"at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions)"
]

Here is my code for LambdaEntryPoint.cs & Program.cs:
public class LambdaEntryPoint : Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction
{  
    protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseStartup<Program>()
            .UseLambdaServer();
    }        
}

Here is my part of my Program.cs with addition of lambda stuff
// .....
builder.Services.AddAWSLambdaHosting(LambdaEventSource.RestApi);

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

// In your Configure method:
app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

I'm using serverless.template approach to push my lambda function to S3 bucket and Stack, which works fine.
At the end my lambda and api gateway throws the error mentioned above.
Being newbie to deploy ASP.NET Core 8 Web API to AWS world, I'm sure I'm missing something important here. Can someone assist me to cross the blocker. Please reply if you need more information.
Also I tried to mimic StartUp.cs and try to use in my LambdaEntryPoint override class, but that gives another error as shown here:
builder
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseStartup<StartUp>()
    .UseLambdaServer();

Error:
{   "errorType": "NullReferenceException",   "errorMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",   "stackTrace": [
    "at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyFunction.MarshallRequest(InvokeFeatures features, APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest apiGatewayRequest, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)",
    "at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.AbstractAspNetCoreFunction`2.FunctionHandlerAsync(TREQUEST request, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)",
    "at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.HandlerWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass26_0`2.<<GetHandlerWrapper>b__0>d.MoveNext()",
    "--- End of stack trace from previous location ---",
    "at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.LambdaBootstrap.InvokeOnceAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)"   ] }

Locally the API works fine!
Sorry about the long message, Just tried to provide much information as possible.
Thanks in advance

Would recommend you to watch my this video - Building a Serverless ASP.NET Core Web API using AWS Lambda and Amazon API Gateway REST API.

thanks for the response. I have already watched this video. but no luck.
ended up using StarUp.cs instead of Program.cs for this purpose. I know its not the best practice as MS removed Startup.cs as default

How did you create this project. It seem you mixed both the things, old startup.cs file as well as program.cs file. Which AWS Lambda project template you used in Visual Studio or CLI?

Thanks! I'm using ASP .NET Core API Serverless Application template which comes with serverless.template file. I like to use the Program.cs file as default, but only had to tweak this with Startup due to this error as I explained in my original post above.
"cause": {   "errorType": "InvalidOperationException",   "errorMessage": "A public method named 'ConfigureProduction' or 'Configure' could not be found in the 'Program' type.",
I really want to use like builder.UseStartup()
